# How does baking soda relieve an itch?

Tags: itching, eczema, baking-soda, histamine

Searching around the web, I found a lot of resources saying that baking soda (NaHCO₃) is good to relieve an itch. For example, this article [Baking Soda for You Skin: Is It Safe, When to Use, and More](https://www.healthline.com/health/beauty-skin-care/baking-soda-for-skin#conditions-it-may-help)

> Baking soda is not a cure for eczema, but it may help relieve the itch associated with it. The National Eczema Association recommends adding 1/4 cup baking soda to a warm (not hot) bath and soaking for 10 to 15 minutes. Gently towel dry your skin and moisturize afterwards.

How does it work? I get that itching is caused by histamine, so does it simply reduces the histamine, or does it block the receptors, similar to how anti-histamine works? I tried searching for [`baking soda itch review`](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=baking%20soda%20itch%20review&btnG=) on Google Scholar, but there are no useful articles at a glance.